# "How can I use R to extract only one channel from a multi-channel WAV file in order to enable soundecology to calculate indices?"

Tags: r, audio, package, channel

I have a multi-channel WAV file with four channels, and I need to extract only one of the channels (let's say channel 1) in order to enable soundecology to calculate indices. How can I use R to read the WAV file, extract only the first channel, and save it as a new WAV file that can be used by soundecology for index calculation?

i m using Audacity to erase those channels manually so that i can calculate the ecoacoustic index

Answer (score 2):

The `tuneR::channel()` function can be used to extract a channel from a multichannel wav file.

Since the original post does not contain a reproducible example, we'll download a sample multichannel WAV file from the internet, read it and extract a channel.

Then we'll write the output file and test with a WAV file player, and play the file to confirm that the output is valid and plays the expected sound.

```
# download an example multichannel wav file
download.file("https://www.jensign.com/bdp95/7dot1voiced/7dot1voiced.zip",
              "./data/7dot1voiced.zip",mode="wb")
unzip("./data/7dot1voiced.zip",exdir="./data/unzip")
```

Per the documentation at [jensign.com](https://www.jensign.com/bdp95/7dot1voiced/index.html) the downloaded zip file contains a wav 5.1 file with six channels, and a 7.1 file with 8 channels. We'll read the 5.1 file, and expect it to contain 6 channels.

```
library(tuneR)

# read WAV file as multichannel
aFile <- readWave("./data/unzip/Nums_5dot1_24_48000.wav",toWaveMC = TRUE)

# calculate # of channels
nchannel(aFile)
```

Here we confirm that the file contains six channels.

```
> nchannel(aFile)
[1] 6
```

We extract the first channel and print its channel info.

```
# extract channel 1
channel1 <- aFile[,1]

# print object info
channel1
```

Notice that the print shows there is only one channel in the extracted object.

```
> channel1

WaveMC Object
    Number of Samples:      434386
    Duration (seconds):     9.05
    Samplingrate (Hertz):   48000
    Number of channels:     1
    PCM (integer format):   TRUE
    Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    24
```

If you're using the Microsoft Windows operating system, it's also easy to play the WAV file and confirm it that it contains a human voice saying the word "one," followed by a period of silence.

```
play(channel1)
```

...which brings up the Windows Media Player in a popup window to process the  file.

[image]

On other operating systems one can use the `player=` argument to specify the path to a media player on the local computer that can process WAV files.

Finally, we write the channel to an output file, and outside R, play the saved file to confirm it contains the expected content.

```
# write to file
writeWave(channel1,"./data/channel1.wav")

# when the output file is played it will say "one" for the first channel, since
# each channel contains a voice saying the channel number
```

We can extract a different channel and demonstrate that the process works for other channels. Here we'll extract channel 3, save the resulting file, and confirm that we hear a voice saying "three."

```
# extract channel 3
channel3 <- aFile[,3]

# print object info
channel3
```

We see that the `channel3` object has one channel.

```
> channel3

WaveMC Object
    Number of Samples:      434386
    Duration (seconds):     9.05
    Samplingrate (Hertz):   48000
    Number of channels:     1
    PCM (integer format):   TRUE
    Bit (8/16/24/32/64):    24
```

Now we write the channel data to an output WAV file.

```
# write to file
writeWave(channel3,"./data/channel3.wav")
```

Listening to the output file is left as an exercise for the reader.